# what is parent stand in selector in angular 2

Tags: angular2-select

import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

import "./loadingSpinner.component.css!";

```
@Component({
    selector: "loading-spinner-Parent",
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="showSpinner" class="loader-directive-wrapper">
            <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>`
})
export class LoadingSpinnerComponent {
    @Input() public showSpinner: boolean = false;
}
```

Comment: The text assigned to the selector tag is what will be used in the template to include the component into the DOM. The "parent" here is just part of the name. Usage will be <loading-spinner-Parent></loading-spinner-Parent>